# Xamarin ios custom WKWebview renderer resolve youtube video by default full screen show

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, wkwebview

I have an open URL in WKWebview on this web-page show this contains a youtube video view but in WKWebview it's by default show in full screen.

how to show youtube video as inline or show as it's the frame size, I have implemented all below code but not getting success.

```
var configuration = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
 configuration.Preferences = preferences;
 configuration.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;
 configuration.MediaPlaybackRequiresUserAction = true;

 webView = new WKWebView(Frame, configuration);
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do something similar, to display the video on my device screen, and I found that the only free way to do this because of YouTube's strict rules, is by loading the embed through HTML on a webView page.

I has to add a lot of properties to properly define the embed size. And as you can see in the picture, it worked!

[image: iOS Screenshot with youtube video in page]

This is the code I ended up have to use:

```
var html = string.Format("<html>{0}<body><iframe width='{1}' height='{2}' src='{3}' frameborder='0' allow='autoplay; encrypted-media' allowfullscreen></iframe></body></html>",header, screenWidth, playerHeight, videoUrl);
```

[Here's the sample](https://github.com/saamerm/XF-YouTubeChannel-Streaming) where I finally ended up doing it in Xamarin Forms.